# Max Http post Request size for Mobilefirst 7.1 with Liberty Profile

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

We are in need to upload images from the client mobile devices to the server. Few devices really give a big size of images like 5 MB to 16 MB. 
What is the max size limit for MFP with liberty profile? If there is any limit can that be increased?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any specific limit in Liberty Core for the size of a POST body.  However, if you have an IBM HTTP Server in front of your Liberty server, you may need to adjust the "PostSizeLimit" setting in IHS plug-in as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_generate_plugin_cfg_xml.html).  A size of "-1" is unlimited.